# Redirect code with "?" does not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect this page:

```
http://orbit-cs.com/Orbit/SendFile.asp?DBID=1&LNGID=1&GID=882
```

To this:

```
http://orbit-cs.com/news/
```

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^DBID=1&LNGID=1&GID=882$ 
RewriteRule ^orbit-cs.com/Orbit/SendFile.asp?$ orbit-cs.com/news [L,R=301]
```

Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: and this what I wrote in the .htaccess file:
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^DBID=1&LNGID=1&GID=882$
RewriteRule ^http://orbit-cs.com/Orbit/SendFile.asp?$ http://orbit-cs.com/news/ [L,R=301]

Any idea way it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

You don't match domain name in `RewriteRule`. That is used for matching REQUEST_URI only. Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^DBID=1&LNGID=1&GID=882$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?Orbit/SendFile\.asp$ orbit-cs.com/news? [NC,L,R=301]
```